# Unable to connect to postgres server remotely(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: database, postgresql, telnet, postgresql-9.5

I am pretty new to postgreSQL. I am running version 9.5 of it on my main machine. I am trying to establish a telnet connection from my virtual machine. Before doing that I have configured the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files to accept connection from remote machine in the same network. 
However when I start the postgresql service using:

```
service postgresql start
```

The process show the status:

```
active(exited)
```

and the telnet connection is also refused(when i run telnet x.x.x.x 5432). Also when i start the postgresql service using

```
systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main
```

the status is active(running) but the telnet connection is still refused. Can anyone tell me how to establish the telnet connection? I dont really know whats going on and I am new here so please dont mind if its a noob question

Comment: do you have multiple versions of postgres installed on the same system? Are you sure that you modified the postgresql.conf and pg_gba.conf files for the version that you are using? 
Can you connect to postgresql locally (executing psql -h localhost) on your main machine?

Comment: Yes I think I am running only one version. But just to be sure, How do I check I if I am running multiple versions or not ?

Comment: Go to the postgresql.conf file of your 9.5 installation (on my ubuntu file it is located in `/etc/postgresql/<postgresql_version>/main`) and check the port property. If you have multiple clusters active at the same time, the 9.5 version may be started on a different port than 5432